# Struggling to write a c program the runs the way this assignment is describing

Tags: c, visual-studio

so the assignment is like this:

"write one C program that asks the user to input the number of coins that the user has and then output the total amount of money the user has. Assume that the user has dimes, nickels, pennies and quarters only.  After the user enters the number of coins for each denomination, the program should output the total amount of money. The program should work with any number of coins entered.
How many pennies do you have? 10

You entered 10

How many nickels do you have? 5

You entered 5

How many dimes do you have? 1

You entered 1

How many quarters do you have? 1

You entered 1

You have $0.70

### Thank you."

The code i wrote looks like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
main() {
    int pennyTotal, nickleTotal, dimeTotal, quarterTotal, result;
    printf("How many pennies do you have?\n");
    scanf_s("%i", &pennyTotal);
    printf("How many nickles do you have?\n");
    scanf_s("%i", &nickleTotal);
    printf("How many dimes do you have?\n");
    scanf_s("%i", &dimeTotal);
    printf("How many quarters do you have?\n");
    scanf_s("%i", &quarterTotal);
    printf("You have\n");
    result = pennyTotal + nickleTotal + dimeTotal + quarterTotal;
    printf(result);
    printf("Thank you.\n");
    system("pause");
```

so far I got the "how many..." part right. It's just the part where I set the values and get the output to be how much money the user has when they enter a random number. I'm so lost but i feel like I'm really close.

Comment: `printf(result)` dos not compile. On my compiler, the error is quite legible: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'const char *' for 1st argument

Comment: "Could use some help" is not a specific technical problem. Please use the title to communicate *what* you're struggling with. Does it crash? Produce incorrect output? Being a beginner doesn't matter, we're all here to share and learn.

Comment: Do you mean you are stuck at: result = 100*pennyTotal + 20*nickleTotal + 10*dimeTotal + 4*quarterTotal?

Comment: Something like that. What I mean is I don't know how write in the program to where pennyTotal would equal 1 cent, dimeTotal would equal 10 cents, nickleTotal would equal 5 cents and quarterTotal equal 25 cents. That way if the user were to put they have 2 quarters, the program would basically be like "user has 2 quarters, quaterTotal=25 so 2*25=50 cents. they have 50cents".

Comment: regardingL:  *result = pennyTotal + nickleTotal + dimeTotal + quarterTotal;*  if I give you 2 quarters and 1 nickle,The amount of money you have is NOT 3,  Rather it is 25*2 + 5*1 = 55 cents

Comment: regarding: `main() {`  there are only 2 valid signatures for `main()`.  They are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`   Note: non compliant compilers, like visual studio, will allow such invalid statements (as no return int modifier on the `main()` signature.

Comment: exactly, I want it to work like that, it's just I don't exactly know how to do it.

Comment: You do not know how to multiply, how to handle quantities with different weighting?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are close. The main problem you have is that `printf(result);` is wrong. You need `printf("%d", result);`

Comment: this does not answer the question about how much money the OP has.